# adding lines to a file in it doesnt exist in python

Tags: python, linux, loops

so what i am doing is first reading the /var/log/secure file for ipaddresses that i want to block and saving that list to a file. then i am trying read that file and determine if the address is outside of the US, and if it is, then i want to block the address in the iptables.

i also want to predetermine if that address has already been added to the iptables before i write to it:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import GeoIP
import os

os.system("cat /var/log/secure | grep 'Failed password for invalid user' | grep -oE '((1?[0-9][0-9]?|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.){3}(1?[0-9][0-9]?|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])' >> /home/user/ipaddresses.txt")

iptables_file = open('/etc/sysconfig/iptables', 'r')
loglist = iptables_file.readlines()
iptables_file.close()
found = False

gi = GeoIP.new(GeoIP.GEOIP_MEMORY_CACHE)

for line in file("/home/user/ipaddresses.txt", "r"):
    line = line[:-1] # strip the last from the line
    #print line, "-", gi.country_code_by_addr(line)

    if str(gi.country_code_by_addr(line)) != "US":
            for ip in loglist:
                    if str(line) in line:
                            print str(line) + " found in iptables, skipping ip address"
                            break
            else:
                    print "adding " + str(line) + " to iptables"
                    #os.system("iptables -A INPUT -s " + str(line) + " -j DROP")

#os.system("service iptables save")
```

obviously i dont want to write to my iptables until i know that its working so thats why i have it commented out. what am i doing wrong? 
this is the error:

```
grep: write error
cat: write error: Broken pipe
```

Comment: Have you tried that command (in your os.system call) on the command line?   Why are you both piping input to grep, and passing it a file on the command line?    Do you have permission to write that output file?

Comment: @GreenAsJade yes i tried the os.system call prior to reading the iptables first. and i am running this as root so i do have the right permissions and i chmod +x the file to make sure

Comment: this line runs fine "if str(line) in line" it gets messed up in the "if not found"

Comment: Comment out the os.system() call and see if it still fails.  That would be rather suprising.

Comment: @GreenAsJade i believe it is commented out

Comment: I'm referring to the _first_ os.system() call.   It is the only place that grep is being called, as far as we can see, in your code.

Comment: oh sorry. i just commented it out and am still not getting any return from my "if not found" portion of the loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second grep command:

grep -oE '((1?[0-9]...[0-5])' /var/log/secure

has /var/log/secure as an argument. That should not be there. It is reading the file and not reading standard input, and that is causing the error.

Comment: I'm not convinced that this causes grep to say "write error".

Comment: @nortoon it prints to the ipaddresses.txt file just fine

Comment: I replicated using a similar command on my machine, and it grep did say that.  The thing is that the command pipe is not doing what you think it is doing. The cat and first grep are basically ignored. The second grep on the command line is processing the secure file from its arguments, not standard input. So anything matching the last grep is printing, no filter for "Failed password"

Comment: how can i fix it using those similar parameters?

Comment: Huh - apologies.  I tried the same and did _not_ get that.   Can you explain why it says it?   I certainly agree it makes no sense to have it there :)

Comment: The first grep for "Failed password" is writing the pipe. At some point, the pipe fills up and the first grep blocks on write. The second grep processes the file and exits, never having read the pipe. When it exits, the first grep's blocked write returns an error code. If you use a small file, you don't see it because the first grep writes the buffer and finishes before the pipe buffers are full.

Comment: hmm i dont know haha. i removed it and am now not getting the grep error but its also not printing out:
    if not found:
        print "adding " + str(line) + " to iptables"

Comment: I would restructure the code a little, though. Instead of found = True use break and then use an else clause instead of the if not found. What you have now should print. That gets rid of the found variable entirely. You are initializing that in the wrong place, should be inside the "for line" loop.

Comment: To make that a little clearer, you should line the else up with the "for ip" loop so that if the loop runs all the way through, what's in the else is executed.

Comment: @nortoon ah i see. thanks. unfortunately its still not printing out my else. i feel like its sooooo close.

Comment: i edited the code to reflect the changes suggested. is this right?

Comment: Not the problem, but you are using >> in your system command. That means the file will be appended to all the time. Not likely what you want, a single ">" would just give you the new stuff. Is the "found in iptables" ever printing?  I don't know what GEOip object does or if it will ever return non-"US". Try inserting a print of that object right before the if.

Comment: if str(line) in line is suspicious. You mean str(ip) in line?

Comment: Thanks. that fixed it! thanks for sticking with me to the end @nortoon

Comment: No problem, kind of fun.